# Delphi messagebox appearing behind other form

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, messagebox

I am using the code below to create a messagebox in Delphi 7. However I also have another form on screen who's `FormStyle` is set to `fsStayOnTop` and the messagebox appears behind this form.

Is there any way to force the messagebox to appear in front?

```
    if Application.MessageBox('Amessage here','Title', +MB_APPLMODAL + MB_ICONQUESTION + MB_YESNO) = IDNO then
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997079/delphi-how-to-prevent-forms-msgboxes-to-move-under-prior-form

Comment: Avoid using `Application.MessageBox`. Instead use WinAPI `MessageBox` function and pass it a `HWND` of your topmost form. Additionally, you can use `MB_TASKMODAL` flag to make sure the dialog will popup on top of every other form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call [`NormalizeTopMosts`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_NormalizeTopMosts.html) prior to showing the message box.

> Use NormalizeTopMosts to allow a message box or dialog box that is
>   displayed using the Windows API functions (such as MessageBox and
>   MessageDlg) directly, appear on top of a topmost form. Otherwise the
>   topmost form remains on top, and may obscure the message box.

(Hope it's available in Delphi 7.)

**Edit**: Not sure about the downvote. If it hints in the direction that OP should use the native [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and set its parent HWND to the topmost window - I would agree. But maybe this is not possible for some reason.

Comment: Hmm. There are downvotes on all 3 answers so far, with no explanation/justification.  Not sure what's up with that.  SO doesn't have a "hit-and-run" badge.

Comment: Without a hint these downvotes are so pointless. +1 for the badge :)

Comment: I'm not seeing down votes, however as indicated, it may have been because the question specifically asks about using application.messagebox - there is a lot of code in that method before the windows.messagebox is called - mostly dealing with multiple monitors and task windows.  Replacing the current call as specified in the question may cause undesirable results in the environment.

Answer (score 2):

In `Windows.pas` you can find more flags to `MessageBox()`:

```
MB_APPLMODAL = $00000000;
MB_SYSTEMMODAL = $00001000;
MB_TASKMODAL = $00002000;
```

Read about them in [MessageBox documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can even use `MB_TOPMOST` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try MB_TASKMODAL flag instead of MB_APPLMODAL.