# Is calling ShowModal with setting PopupParent a good idea and is it necessary in newer Delphi versions?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

To prevent newly created modal windows to become hidden under their modal parent window I got used to always set `PopupParent` when calling `ShowModal` (as adviced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997079/delphi-how-to-prevent-forms-msgboxes-to-move-under-prior-form), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743713/newly-created-modal-window-loses-focus-and-become-inacessible-in-windows-vista) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639125/form-is-hidden-behind-other-forms-when-showmodal-is-called)):

```
function TMyForm.ShowModal(ParentForm: TCustomForm): Integer;
begin
    PopupParent := ParentForm;
    Result := inherited ShowModal;
end;
```

But when debugging (a problem of lost form placement, set in FormCreate) I realized that setting `PopupParent` leads to a call to `ReCreateWindow`, thus destroying and recreating the underlying Windows screen object.

My questions:

1. Is it a good idea to always set `PopupParent` - what might be
   resulting problems? Do viable alternatives exist?
2. Is this still necessary in newer versions of
   Delphi (I am using D2006 at the moment but plan to update)?

**EDIT:**

I think all the linked questions above tackle the same problem, which is best described by the [3rd link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639125/form-is-hidden-behind-other-forms-when-showmodal-is-called):

> [A form is opened] with ShowModal, this form opens another with ShowModal, so we 
>   have stacked modal forms. There is sometimes a problem that when we call ShowModal 
>   in new form, it hides behind previous forms, instead of showing on top. After pressing 
>   alt+tab, form comes back to the top [...]

Comment: Does this still apply? I never do this (but I've used D2007 and DXE2). The linked posts are from 2009 and 2010.

Comment: @JanDoggen I got these kind of errors reported for Win7 and Win8 for my application compiled under D2006. (But they occur rarely.) Whether they still occur with newer Delphi versions is part of, what I would like to know.

Comment: Occurs in XE2 too (at least under Win7).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, check out what Alois wondered.

Comment: @Edijs all very imprecise

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I edited the question to be more precise about the original problem. I think Edijs is referring to this behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

This question is quite old, but still relevant. The best source of information about this is from Allen Bauer himself:
http://blog.therealoracleatdelphi.com/2004/02/popupmode-and-popupparent_10.html

(wayback: 
https://web.archive.org/web/20160324062228/http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2004/02/10/295 )

And there you find this: 
"If you explicitly set the PopupMode property to pmAuto prior to ShowModal, like at design-time, then the recreate isn’t necessary."

This way your code should be:

```
function TMyForm.ShowModal(ParentForm: TCustomForm): Integer;
begin
    PopupMode := pmAuto;
    PopupParent := ParentForm;
    Result := inherited ShowModal;
end;
```

Comment: New blog post url is: [community.embarcadero.com](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/popupmode-and-popupparent-295)

Comment: @ventiseis Link fixed. Now pointing to personal Allen Bauer's blog which contains a copy of all posts he created during Embarcadero times.

Comment: Not sure if it will work, because as per finding by @dummzeuch below, in `TCustomForm.set_PopupParent`, `FPopupMode` will be changed to `pmExplicit` when changing `PopupParent`

Comment: @EdwinYip I only edited that post for some grammar and spelling errors. The content is fully ventiseis' .

Answer (score 3):

After having spent 2 hours debugging and reading VCL code, I'll append my findings to this topic. In Delphi 10 Seattle, the behaviour is like this:

- form window handles are allocated while creating the form by its constructor, because in `TCustomForm.ReadState(Reader: TReader)` the client width of the form is set which leads to the call to `CreateWnd`
- so even if you put `pmAuto` prior `ShowModal` the window has to be recreated

Finally, the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.PopupMode) mentions:

> The PopupMode property is automatically set to `pmAuto` when the `ShowModal` method is called.

So there are these lines in `ShowModal`:

```
if (PopupMode = pmNone) and (Application.ModalPopupMode <> pmNone) then
begin
  RecreateWnd;
  //..
```

So to make this work, you have to change `Application.ModalPopupMode` as well, but this also recreates the window.

So my advice is:

- set the value for `PopupMode`  (`pmAuto`) directly in your form (`dfm` file)
- setting both `PopupParent` and `PopupMode` makes little sense because they are tied together `PopupParent` sets `pmExplicit`, and `pmAuto` resets the popup parent to `nil`

Comment: Re #2, same in XE4's `TCustomForm.set_PopupParent`, `FPopupMode` will be changed to `pmExplicit` when changing `PopupParent`